# Microsoft Word Ruler Markers

Tags: macos, microsoft-word-2016

[image]I noticed there was this black arrow in the ruler for one of my word documents which I see occasionally. This black arrow gives no information when you hover over it with the mouse, but it seems to be giving the document on the left the proper settings for indentation. I was wondering if there was a name for this marker and why it is not present on the right document.

Comment: A screen shot would help us understand your question.
Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Sorry, I intended to post an image but I forgot

Comment: Which version of Word?

Comment: Word 2016 for mac

Comment: Good. I thought it was a Mac version. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I was wondering if there was a name for this marker?

It is a left tab stop marker (in Word for Mac).

> Why it is not present on the right document?

You haven't added a left tab stop.

---

#### Set or clear a tab stop

> You can set the following types of tab stops:
>
> [image: Left tab] - A Left Tab stop sets the start position of text
>   that will then run to the right as you type.
>
> [image: Center tab] - A Center Tab stop sets the position of the
>   middle of the text. The text centers on this position as you type.
>
> [image: Right tab] - A Right Tab stop sets the right end of the
>   text. As you type, the text moves to the left.
>
> [image: Decimal tab] - A Decimal Tab stop aligns numbers around a
>   decimal point. Independent of the number of digits, the decimal point
>   will be in the same position. (You can align numbers around a decimal
>   character only; you cannot use the decimal tab to align numbers around
>   a different character, such as a hyphen or an ampersand symbol.)
>
> [image: Bar tab] - A Bar Tab stop doesn't position text. It inserts
>   a vertical bar at the tab position.

Source [Set or clear a tab stop](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Set-or-clear-a-tab-stop-f11b63f5-aa77-4cdb-96ad-94a7f1e56d06)

Answer (score 0):

The arrows are called "Tab Stops".

Read [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-tabs-in-a-Word-2016-for-Mac-document-1ad74721-9543-4cad-b6bd-6b1e722f031f) how to add and use them in Word for Mac (based on the screenshot you attached).